# Reading a cookie into textbox (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, cookies, var, onunload

I wrote a cookie to hold the value of txtFirstName on the unload event. This is done on the unload event so it can be written without the need for a submit button:

```
<head runat="server">
<title>Cookie Test</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function WriteCookies() {
        var d = new Date();
        var n = document.getElementById('txtFirstName').value;
        d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);
        document.cookie = "CTFirstName = " + n +"; expires = " 
+ d.toGMTString() + "";
    }
</script>
</head>

<body onunload="WriteCookies()">
```

When someone closes their browser and opens it again I would like the cookie value to be read into the textbox. However I'm having trouble completing this. Can anyone offer help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a function to read cookie back.

here is javascript part

```
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
    }
    return "";
}

function GetCookies() {
    document.getElementById('txtFirstName').value = getCookie('CTFirstName');
}
```

and here is HTML part to trigger functions.

```
<body onunload="WriteCookies()" onload="GetCookies()">
```

Comment: So I have that function running on the load event, but I'm not completely sure how to read the value into the txtFirstName onload.